# How to maintain R (renv) project

Tags: r, package-management, renv

My colleagues and I are working on a book with Bookdown in RStudio. Since I create a lot of graphics with ggplot and therefore I have many dependencies to other packages (ggplot, ggforce, gganimate, ...), I added renv in the course of the book to take care of package management. After a clean installation of my Windows I do now have problems to set up the project again, because there were updates from R to version 3.6.3 and used packages.

Initial state of the project with renv was R with version 3.6.2, which I reinstalled. After opening the project I run `renv::restore()` to restore the environment with all packages. Currently only the package nloptr (version 1.2.1) has a bug, because it has to build the package from source.

```
Installing minqa [1.2.4] ...
    OK (linked cache)
Installing nloptr [1.2.1] ...
    FAILED
Error installing package 'nloptr':
==================================

* installing *source* package 'nloptr' ...
** package 'nloptr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG       -I"/x64/include"   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c init_nloptr.c -o init_nloptr.o
init_nloptr.c:35:19: fatal error: nlopt.h: No such file or directory
 #include "nlopt.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:208: init_nloptr.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'nloptr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Ralph/DOCUME~1/ML2/ml2-buch/renv/staging/1/nloptr'
Fehler: install of package 'nloptr' failed
```

To work around this error I install the package manually via:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.7/nloptr_1.2.1.zip"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="binary")
```

After that all packages can be installed but now, many of them show the warning `package 'X' was built under R version 3.6.3`.

What's the point of *renv* if it can't restore the original state, because all packages have been changed by an update of R? How can I manage an R project properly ?

Comment: I commiserate with the dilemma, ralph. This *might* be a bug with `renv` (I'm not positive). But for clarity, is your issue with `nloptr` non-compilability, is it `renv` not opting for binary packages, or is that you don't like the *"built under"* warnings?

Comment: @r2evans thanks you for your sympathy ^^. The bigger problem of both is that `nloptr` (maybe only Windows) can't be installed automatically in the *locked* version anymore. So you have to start again from the beginning to set up your environment: either you have to build the needed packages yourself or a new version has to be installed, which might have a new behaviour.
At the moment it was only 1 package but what about in half a year when 10 packages can't be built anymore and a new colleague wants to continue writing the book ?

Answer (score 4):

The underlying issue here is that `nloptr` was recently updated to version 1.2.2.1, and so binaries for 1.2.1 are no longer available on CRAN.

The simplest solution, then, is to upgrade to the latest version of `nloptr`, so that you can access the newer binary. Alternatively, you can use a checkpointed [MRAN](https://mran.microsoft.com/) repository locked to that particular point in time so that binaries available on that day can be served.

If you want to be able to install `nloptr` from sources, you might consider upgrading to the development version of `renv`. You can use `renv::equip()` to download the requisite libraries needed to compile `nloptr` (and some other R packages) from sources. For example:

```
> renv::equip()
The following external software tools will be installed:

    curl-7.68.0-win32-mingw.zip
    glpk32.zip
    glpk64.zip
    local323.zip
    nlopt-2.4.2.zip
    spatial324.zip

Tools will be installed into '~/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft'.

Do you want to proceed? [y/N]: y
Retrieving 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/extsoft/curl-7.68.0-win32-mingw.zip' ...
    OK [downloaded 2.9 Mb in 1.5 secs]
Retrieving 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/extsoft/glpk32.zip' ...
    OK [downloaded 457.7 Kb in 1 secs]
Retrieving 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/extsoft/glpk64.zip' ...
    OK [downloaded 481.6 Kb in 1 secs]
Retrieving 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/extsoft/local323.zip' ...
    OK [downloaded 9.6 Mb in 2.3 secs]
Retrieving 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/extsoft/nlopt-2.4.2.zip' ...
    OK [downloaded 752.6 Kb in 1.2 secs]
Retrieving 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/extsoft/spatial324.zip' ...
    OK [downloaded 20.9 Mb in 2.6 secs]
* External software successfully updated.
The following entries will be added to ~/.R/Makevars:

    LOCAL_SOFT = C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft
    LIB_XML = C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft
    LOCAL_CPPFLAGS = -I"$(LOCAL_SOFT)/include"
    LOCAL_LIBS = -L"$(LOCAL_SOFT)/lib$(R_ARCH)" -L"$(LOCAL_SOFT)/lib"

These tools will be used when compiling R packages from source.

Do you want to proceed? [y/N]: y
* '~/.R/Makevars' has been updated.

> install.packages("nloptr", type = "source")
* installing *source* package 'nloptr' ...
** package 'nloptr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/R/R-36~1.2RC/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/include"     -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -c dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R/R-36~1.2RC/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/include"  -I"/i386/include"   -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -c init_nloptr.c -o init_nloptr.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o nloptr.dll tmp.def dummy.o init_nloptr.o nloptr.o -L/i386/lib -lnlopt_cxx -LC:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/lib/i386 -LC:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/lib -LC:/R/R-36~1.2RC/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Users/kevin/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/R/R-36~1.2RC/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/include"     -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -c dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R/R-36~1.2RC/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/include"  -I"/x64/include"   -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -c init_nloptr.c -o init_nloptr.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o nloptr.dll tmp.def dummy.o init_nloptr.o nloptr.o -L/x64/lib -lnlopt_cxx -LC:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/lib/x64 -LC:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/renv/extsoft/lib -LC:/R/R-36~1.2RC/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/kevin/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'nloptr'
    finding HTML links ... done
    auglag                                  html  
    bobyqa                                  html  
    ccsaq                                   html  
    check.derivatives                       html  
    cobyla                                  html  
    crs2lm                                  html  
    direct                                  html  
    is.nloptr                               html  
    isres                                   html  
    lbfgs                                   html  
    mlsl                                    html  
    mma                                     html  
    neldermead                              html  
    newuoa                                  html  
    nl.grad                                 html  
    nl.opts                                 html  
    nloptr-package                          html  
    nloptr                                  html  
    nloptr.get.default.options              html  
    nloptr.print.options                    html  
    print.nloptr                            html  
    sbplx                                   html  
    slsqp                                   html  
    stogo                                   html  
    tnewton                                 html  
    varmetric                               html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (nloptr)

The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW4Mr1M\downloaded_packages'
```

You can install the development version of `renv` with:

```
renv::upgrade(version = "master")
```

Make sure to restart the R session after updating `renv`.